# Date.today time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, activerecord, scope, timezone

I have a scope that pulls all calls from the database with a status of open, has units assigned, and a transfer_date <= Date.today.

```
scope :open_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["call_units.unit_id IS NOT NULL"]).where("EXTRACT(DAY FROM transfer_date) <= ? AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transfer_date) <= ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month).order("calls.id ASC") }
```

The problem I'm having is if I set a call's transfer date to today at 9:30pm the call is not included in the scope.  I assume this has to do with UTC/timezone.  I'm trying to find out what the best way to write this scope is so I can pull all calls <= Date.today and have the correct results show up.

I'm using postgres btw ergo the EXTRACT in the query.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've used this scope and have been able to pull all calls up to today at the end of day.  Looks like it accommodates for the Timezone issue as well.

```
scope :open_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["call_units.unit_id IS NOT NULL"]).where("transfer_date <= ?", Time.zone.today.end_of_day) }
```